# How to put condition in Spring Bean XML

Tags: spring, spring-bean

how to put an if condition to conditionally load a list. My list has 2 items but I want to put condition on both of the item. If condition is met then only they should be added to list. Condition can be a property check. For example if property ${addBeanOne} is true then only add bean one.

```
<bean class="MyClass">              
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <!- condition start here -->
            <ref bean="bean1"/>
            <!- condition end here -->          
            <ref bean="bean2"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring profiles:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-xml

Comment: can you write down and don't paste links, please.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but profile is not what I am looking for. I expect some EL stuff.

Comment: I don't know other option, for beans created by java - you can use normal java-condition in method responsible for creation.
If you find other solution, let me know I'm interesting solution for xml.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it the way you have (short hand).

You can "build up" different "list"(s) and inject those.

for example:

```
    <bean id="xmlStringBeanFive" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="FiveValue"/>
      </bean>


<beans profile="default">

    <bean id="xmlStringBeanOne" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="OneValue"/>
      </bean>

    <bean id="xmlStringBeanTwo" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="TwoValue"/>
      </bean>

    <util:list id="xmlStringsAsListBean"
               value-type="java.lang.String">
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanOne"/>
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanTwo"/>
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanFive"/>
    </util:list>

</beans>



<beans profile="!default">

    <bean id="xmlStringBeanEight" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="EightValue"/>
      </bean>

    <bean id="xmlStringBeanNine" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="NineValue"/>
      </bean>

    <util:list id="xmlStringsAsListBean"
               value-type="java.lang.String">
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanEight"/>
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanNine"/>
        <ref bean="xmlStringBeanFive"/>
    </util:list>

</beans>





    <bean id="xmlClassThatTakesCollectionOfStringsAsConstructorArgumentBean"
          class="com.my.stuff.ClassThatTakesCollectionOfStringsAsConstructorArgument">
        <constructor-arg ref="xmlStringsAsListBean"/>
    </bean>
```

The key here is that "xmlStringsAsListBean" is defined twice....but under different spring-profiles.

Note, you do NOT have to "double up" the same bean ("Five" in the silly example).  You just need single-source-of-truth-bean definition...and "re-use" it as needed.